# datepicker, place the window to the right

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I use Angular 13, Bootstrap 5 and ngx-bootstrap-fix-datepicker version 5 for my project.

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap-fix-datepicker": "^5.6.8",
```

My problem: I would like to place the calendar to the right and reduce the window.
Do you think it's possible? Because I have no idea.

[datePicker - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q26a.png)

```
<div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
   <div class="col text-end">
      <label for="startDate" class="form-label">Date de départ</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <input type="text " class="form-control form-max-width " name="startDate " [(ngModel)]="startDate " bsDatepicker [maxDate]="endDate " [required]="!!endDate " autocomplete="off ">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for angular:**

You can add the `placement` property to your input tag like:

```
<input type="text " class="form-control form-max-width " name="startDate " [(ngModel)]="startDate " bsDatepicker [maxDate]="endDate " [required]="!!endDate " autocomplete="off " placement="right">
```

The other options you can use are "left | right | bottom | top"

**Old answer:**

You can all the following JavaScript to offset the top and left margin. Make sure to update the variable names to match your own.

```
$('input.date').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        inst.dpDiv.css({
            marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', 
            marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But, unfortunately, I have to use only Angular in my project.

Comment: You can use the `placement` property for that. Have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks very much ! It works. Do you think it's possible to minimize the calendar window?

Comment: You should be able to do that with some CSS using the width and height fields

Comment: Thank you ! It work [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51062003-urfipa?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)